# How should I configure a CAA DNS record for use with the AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: certificate-authority, amazon-route53, pki, amazon-acm

AWS Route 53 [now allows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CAAFormat) the creation of `CAA` records to restrict the certificate authorities that may issue a certificate for a domain. I'd like to use an `issue` directive to restrict the issue of certificates for my domain like in the following example:

```
example.org. CAA 128 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

I obtain certificates for my domain from Amazon's Certificate Manager (ACM). How should I configure a domain that restricts issue of certificates to this service? I don't want to get this wrong in case I break the automatic renewal of the certificate!

Comment: Before you add *any* CAA entry, open up the certificates you use in a browser and confirm that they are indeed issued by the authority you expect (in case of ACM, that should be Amazon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2017-09**

The official ACM guide in the AWS guide contains a section regarding CAA:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html

It does contain an example identical the one below, claims that ACM now does respects CAA configuration, and clarifies that no flag should be set (`flags=0`):

> if you do not have a CAA record that specifies one of the following
> four Amazon CAs, ACM cannot issue a certificate to your domain or
> subdomain

Please bear in mind that until Amazon promises unconditional CAA validation in their certification practice statement,

> CAA checking is optional if the CA or an Affiliate of the CA is the
> DNS Operator (as defined in RFC 7719) of the domain’s DNS.

as per [Ballot 187 of the CAB Forum (effective 2019-09-08)](https://cabforum.org/2017/03/08/ballot-187-make-caa-checking-mandatory/).

**Original Post**

You can just use

```
example.org. CAA 0 issue "amazon.com"
```

**Why amazon.com?**

Because just about any CA out there recommends to use the most memorable domain under their control, and amazon has not yet made any more specific communications.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-3

> issue <Issuer Domain Name> [; <name>=<value> ]* :
> The issue property
> entry authorizes the holder of the domain name  or a party acting under the explicit authority of the holder
> of that domain name to issue certificates for the domain in which
> the property is published.

**Why not use flags (e.g. `flags=128`: mark it critical)?**

Because, as of now (2017-08), Amazon doesnt care for the CAA record, so setting it up, potentially not adhering to guidelines they publish at a later time, you are just preparing yourself for some headache in figuring out what went wrong.

Amazon may or may not additionally recommend to use aws.amazon.com and/or an account name, [and their report to browser vendors looks like they do](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/CAInformationReport).

The [Amazon Trust public document repository](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/) contains a document called `Amazon Trust Services Certification Practice Statement v1.X` and there you can search for "CAA". In v1.0.5 this states

> Amazon Root CAs do not check CAA records prior to issuing certificates.

Comment: Thanks - this is useful. I think "potentially not adhering to guidelines they publish at a later time" is probably the key point - the safest option (from an uptime perspective) is probably to leave this for now and wait until Amazon publish the correct configuration.